# Report name with special character "!"

Tags: report, abap

I created a custom report in abap with the name `Zload_table` and when I go to activate I also see the report `!load_table`.
Could you tell me how the report is generated with name `!Load_table`?
And what the special character means `!`?

Thank you

Comment: It used to be a temporary name for a program never activated but executed in test mode (from `SE38`) . But I think it was in old ABAP versions. There are a few more details in the [note 1337406 - Exclamation mark in front of job or program name](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1337406/E).

Comment: @SandraRossi maybe to convert the comment  to an answer?